# Just hoping someone out there recognizes this bike and can help identify it

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike, aluminum

Assuming this is a 90s era aluminum frame with only a head badge sticker to identify it, no name or model printed anywhere. RX100 RD, DeoreXT FD, Sugino triple crank and Exage500EX brakes. the fork is missing but it takes a 1" steerer.
I've scrolled through tons of google image searches and checked to see if the serial# was registered but have zero results so far. Thanks for taking a look and any info you can provide.

[image: frame]

[image: head badge]

[image: handle bars]

[image: rear derailleur]

[image: front derailleur]

[image: crank]

[image: brakes]

Comment: Nice bike!  I think the headtube badge is your best bet if someone can identify it.  Looks like a stylised R to me.

Comment: I suspect the chainring/cranks and FD have been replaced at some point - those don't fit well with the rest of the items which are all road-based.

Comment: Thanks! Agreed it's an odd group of components and that looks like a R to me too but it hasn't turned up anywhere else on the internet yet.